# Executions are not logged in Stackdriver logs in the Apps Script Dashboard

Tags: debugging, logging, google-apps-script

I am working on an Google Apps Script in a Google Sheets.

Yesterday I could see all executions of the script, trace errors, and see the result of all `Logger.log` lines in the Stackdriver logs in the Apps Script Dashboard. However, nothing was logged in the "Logs" (accessed via Ctrl+Enter).

Today, I get no information in neither the Dashboard or the Logs when I run my script. I have made sure that there are no filters active in the Dashboard.

Does anyone know that is going on?

Comment: How about `console.log()`?

Comment: Is this happening for all projects or just one specific project?

Comment: Added a console.log line to the code and now I can see that and the logger.log calls in the stackdriver.

However, it feels a bit random that it would have solved the problem and made all the logger.log calls as well. But I hope the issue stays away.

Answer (score -1):

There is probably an error happening before it gets to the Logger.log(). Revert back to Rhino from V8 (Run > Disable new Apps Script runtime...), if you need to,  and look in View > Execution Transcript.

Comment: Dear Andrew, Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately non luck with it: "No execution transcripts found. Please run your script and try again."

Comment: Logs are now disabled with Rhino